# How do I get multiple checkbox values in FormData?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, form-data

My html form has multiple checkboxes with the same `name` attribute:

```
<form id='cheese-selector'>
  <input type="checkbox" name="cheese" id="limburger" value="Limburger">Limburger</input>
  <input type="checkbox" name="cheese" id="camembert" value="Camembert">Camembert</input>
  <input type="checkbox" name="cheese" id="roquefort" value="Roquefort">Roquefort</input>
  <input type="submit" id="pick-cheese">Pick My Cheese!</input>
</form>
```

I'm submitting it via ajax. When I make a `FormData` object, only the first selected checkbox is included, even if I've checked more than one:

```
$('#limburger').click()
$('#camembert').click()
console.log(FormData(this).get('cheese'))
// 'Limburger'
```

How do I make `FormData` encode all the checked values as an array?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get):

> The get() method of the FormData interface returns the first value associated with a given key from within a FormData object. If you expect multiple values and want all of them, use the getAll() method instead.

Comment: So, reliably getting all the data from unknown HTML forms, in the same form that a web browser would submit it, is not trivial with `FormData`.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite — No. Just use `getAll`.